# Customize ECB menu of Sharepoint hosted add-in

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

How could I hide some menu items from a ECB menu in a Sharepoint add-in, based on permissions? My Sharepoint application is Sharepoint hosted not provider hosted, so the javascript injection method wouldn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Your application will always run with the current users permissions. If a permission level on a item in your menu has a higher permission level than the current user the user won't be able to access it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to use usergroups and javascript? I can't find a workaround ..

Comment: Sure its possible, the best way i'd say would be to check if the current user is a member of a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your help. Finally I've got what I wanted to customize in my page. I've overriden the CreateMenuOption in core.js by creating another file (I've used Chrome to get the code). I've used the following js file too : https://spservices.codeplex.com/ in order to get the group of the connected user.

Answer (score 1):

**Function to check if user is member of specified group**

```js
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {

        var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        currentContext.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);

        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
        currentContext.load(group);

        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        currentContext.load(groupUsers);

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
            var userInGroup = false;
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            OnComplete(userInGroup);
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            OnComplete(false);
        }    
}
```

**usage**

```js
function IsCurrentUserHasContribPerms() 
{
  IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
    {
        // The current user is in the [Members] group!
    }
  });

}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(IsCurrentUserHasContribPerms, 'SP.js');
```

Source from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86912/check-if-user-is-in-a-specified-group)